# Why isn't my map rendering?

Tags: android, google-maps, runtime-error

I started with the Android Studio default Maps app, which has a fragment named `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`, its context `MapsActivity.java`, and its key in `google_maps_api.xml`. I went to the URL specified in `google_maps_api.xml` and generated, then copied back the key provided which starts with `AIza`. Then I ran the app to test it, but the Maps fragment just displayed a beige rectangle with zoom buttons and the Google logo, and none of these affected the view.

In the console, this error appears every time:

```
07-22 13:11:48.811    7275-7340/org.bh.app.ourmap E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

My phone is connected to the internet. **Why won't my map display?**

Comment: did you generate the API key to the right sha1 key? debug and release apps use different keys

Comment: @mapo How can I find out?